# Add rCharts to packrat

Tags: r, rstudio, rcharts, install.packages, packrat

I am working on an R project (R studio) that requires several packages and packrat to manage them. I have been able to find CRAN or binaries for all of them except rCharts which has to be installed with:

```
   require(devtools)
   install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv')
```

This method of installation does not seem to work at all with packrat.

Since this project needs to be easily setup/run on a variety of computers, packrat seems like it is the only solution to keep the required packages in order for this project.

How can I make rCharts work with packrat so that the user does not have to manually install rCharts?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You could download the source code from github and make a binary yourself.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik How can I make a binary from the github code? Also, how can I force packrat to use this binary instead of trying to install from github?

Comment: Probably depends on what you mean by a "binary".

Answer (score 3):

Packrat provides a special function to install packages from github.

```
packrat::install_github("ramnathv/rCharts")
```